# Enviar parâmetro post para restify

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5, restify

Estou tentando enviar parametro para o nodejs com restify, mas está chegando sempre `undefined`

Estou enviando mais ou menos assim:

```
$.ajax({
       url : 'http://localhost:8080/api',
       type: 'post',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {
            ano : ano
        }    
     })
```

E no node estou recebendo assim:

```
server.post('/api/temp/anual', async (req, res, next) =>{

        try{
            const { ano } =  req.params
            console.log( ano )
            res.send( await db.medicao().anual( ano ) )
            next()
        }catch (error) {
            res.send(error)
            next()
        }
    })
```

Só que o valor sempre vem como `undefined`

Se eu tentar pelo postman vai correto

Comment: Descobri: mudei de `req.params` para `req.body`

Comment: Forneça uma resposta para sua própria pergunta, já que descobriu a resposta :)